# Why is my ssh login dropped immedeately after login?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I am trying to connect from a MacBook Air (MacOS 10.14.6) via ssh (password-less) to an ubuntu machine (16.04.6), using a command like

```
ssh aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
```

It always worked fine, I got a prompt and could start working on the remote machine.

However, for about one week, this does not work anymore, without any knowing change I have made to the login process, new users, changing password, changing any keys, upgrading OS, changing `.profile` or `.bashrc` etc. 
I also checked `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` but nothing in there, and I rebooted the ubuntu machine and the Mac, but no change.

The moment I login successfully, I see a message

```
Last login: ... from www.xxx.yyy.zzz
Connection to aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd closed
```

How can I debug what is going on?

**Addendum**

When checking `/var/log/auth.log` I see the following entries:

```
Oct 16 07:02:38 mac353 systemd-logind[1173]: New session 11 of user alex.
Oct 16 07:02:38 mac353 sshd[11834]: Received disconnect from www.xxx.yyy.zzz port 61437:11: disconnected by user
Oct 16 07:02:38 mac353 sshd[11834]: Disconnected from www.xxx.yyy.zzz port 61437
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Oct 16 07:02:38 mac353 sshd[11834]: Received disconnect from www.xxx.yyy.zzz port 61437:11: disconnected by user
```

Is `www.xxx.yyy.zzz` the correct IP address for your MacBook Air at the moment?

It might be that there is another system on the network using the same IP address.
You can initiate a connection normally, but any responses get delivered randomly to both systems participating in the IP address conflict, so the server may have to re-send some of its outgoing packets. Normally the system that is actually actively trying to establish a connection will answer faster, so for a few initial packets it may appear to work out just fine.

But eventually the conflicting system's TCP/IP driver will think "What is this traffic? I have no such TCP connection active right now." and send a TCP Reset packet back to the source of the spurious-looking traffic, i.e. the server. Because the conflicting system has the same IP address as your MacBook, the server has no way to know that the TCP Reset does not actually belong to your connection, and so the server will assume that the TCP Reset means *you* wanted to disconnect. It does not happen immediately because sending of TCP Reset packets is usually a low-priority job within the TCP/IP driver.

This would be a very typical symptom of an IP address conflict.

To find the conflicting system, you might try looking at the MAC address tables of the network switch (if it's a managed switch) or WiFi AP of your local network segment. If your IP address is associated with a MAC address that does not belong to your MacBook, you've found the MAC address of the conflicting system. In a wired network, you could then check which switch port has seen that MAC address, and then just see what's at the other end of the cable.

If you don't have managed switches or don't have access to them, you could try pinging your own IP address and seeing if you get duplicate answers back. Or you could try the `arping` command-line tool to do the same with ARP packets: that will catch even systems that don't answer to pings.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue was a `set -e` which was in a file in `/etc/profile.d` which got installed in a completely different context. After renaming that file the `ssh` login worked again.

```
`set -e`
```

stops the execution of a script if a command has an error ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622198/what-does-set-e-mean-in-a-bash-script)) and is considered bad practice by some.